# Adding <br /> before specific part of text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 paragraphs like this :

```
<p>text bla bla bla owner of the idea : John Smith</p>
<p>text bla bla bla bla bla bla owner of the idea : James Marino</p>
```

Is there any way I could use jQuery to add a new line before "Owner of the idea" till the end of the sentence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `p.html(function(i, v) { return v.replace('owner', '<br>owner'); });` where `p` is a jQuery object containing your paragraph. **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ttA8m/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a copy of your jquery script, try using a `\n` for new line. That work in javascripts.

jQuery WORKING example:

```
 <p id="s">text bla bla bla owner of the idea : John Smith</p>
<p>text bla bla bla bla bla bla owner of the idea : James Marino</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").each(function() {
            var getContent=$(this).text();
            var newString=getContent.replace('owner of the idea','<br />owner of the idea');
            $(this).html(newString);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No, this output is generated by an old CMS I wanna use jQuery to inject the <br /> thanks

Comment: Doh... Than I presume you will need to add a search function in your jquery to search for some string ("owner of the idea" in your case), and replace it with same string, but with `<br />`. Check my post for example.

Comment: There's an extra ")" on the third line I think. I removed it but still get Syntax error probably on the second line I don't know why. Let me post a JS fiddle

Comment: Also for what its worth, you have introduced two globals in your example.  Bad @RRStoyanov!

Comment: @RRStoyanov Your variables are implicit globals. Declare them locally to avoid that...

Comment: entire example is fixed. there was also a typo, but that's fixed too. please remove downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>If the pattern is consistent, you could do a replace based on the `:` character.</strike>

```
 $('p').each(function(){ 
          this.html(this.html().replace(":",":<br />"));
 });
```

**Update**

According to the comment, it looks like I misread the question.  You can still use this same strategy however,

```
  var p = $('p:first');
  p.html(p.html().replace("owner of the idea", "<br />owner of the idea"));
```

Comment: _before_ "owner of the idea:" :)

Comment: @RRStoyanov, my answer was based on his specific example which contained two `p` tags, so it is a non-issue here.  However, he could clearly use an `each` iterator such as in my original answer and in the answer you posted that was clearly inspired by my original answer  ;-) ...  or he could do the replace on the `body` element, but that would assume the `owner of the idea` string occurs only once in the document.

Comment: Good solution - I was starting to write out a long-form substring extraction, append tag, append rest of substring solution, but honestly that was annoying and this is much cleaner. +1  As far as selecting the right paragraph goes, there's no context available to be able to give the correct selector for the initial object.

Comment: @smartcaveman nice one. down vote for your first suggestion turned into up vote :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<br />').insertBefore(selector for your paragraph);
```

I don't know what your surrounding markup looks like, so it's not clear what the best selector for your paragraph would be.

Comment: it doesn't look like the OP is trying to insert before the paragraph, but rather somewhere in the middle

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - I originally took what he was saying to mean the paragraph it was in, but you're right, reading it again it looks like he wants it in the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\bowner of the idea/i,'<br/>$&'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a class on the break then show and hide at will, like so:

html:

```
<br class="break" style="display:none;"/>
```

jquery:

```
$('.break').show();
$('.break').hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

<s>You simply need to prepend the `<br />` to the paragraph using this JavaScript:</s>

```
$("p").prepend("<br />");
```

**Update** I see what you mean now... Try this code:

```
var old=$("p").html();
$("p").html(old.replace(/owner/gi,"<br />owner");
```

Ad@m